# How to control the maximum concurrently running processes?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

There are 5 files: `main.py`, `worker.py`, `cat.py`, `dog.py` and `rabbit.py`. `cat`, `dog` and `rabbit` inherit form `worker` and implement `worker_run()`.

In the `main.py`, I prepare **3 processes** to execute, however don't know how to control the maximum concurrently running process at the same time (eg. 2 processes).

I have tried using the `multiprocessing.Pool`, but it only supports functions outside class (?).

**`main.py`**:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from cat import *
from dog import *
from rabbit import *

p1 = cat()
p2 = dog()
p3 = rabbit()
p1 = start()
p2 = start()
p3 = start()
p1 = join()
p2 = join()
p3 = join()
```

**`worker.py`**:

```
import multiprocessing

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        print "Init"
        self.value = None

    def run(self):
        print "Running"
        self.worker_run()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def worker_run(self):
    """ implement """
    return
```

**`cat.py`**:

```
from worker import *

class cat(Worker):
    def worker_run(self)
        for i in range(10000)
            print "cat run"
```

**`dog.py`**:

```
from worker import *

class dog(Worker):
    def worker_run(self)
        for i in range(10000)
            print "dog run"
```

**`rabbit.py`**:

```
from worker import *

class dog(Worker):
    def worker_run(self)
        for i in range(10000)
            print "rabbit run"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i have try to use multiprocessing.pool , but it only support function without class method"? Can you add an example or explain it further?

Comment: pool = multiprocessing.Pool(process=2)

Comment: funcs = [cat , dog , rabbit]

Comment: for func in enumrate(funcs):

Comment: pool.apply_async(func, args=())
pool.close()
pool.join()

Comment: Could you paste a link to a gist, instead of pasting each line as a comment, please? :)

Comment: and use this method , the run() in worker will not call , so i say it is unuseful

Comment: Plus have you seen the @Bakuriu's solution with Semaphore? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to let at most two methods run concurrently and block the third one until one of the others stopped, you have to use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore)

You must pass the semaphore to the object methods so that they can acquire it.
In your main file you create the semaphore and pass it to the objects:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore
from cat import *
from dog import *
from rabbit import *

semaphore = Semaphore(2)   # at most 2 processes running concurrently
p1 = cat(semaphore)
p2 = dog(semaphore)
p3 = rabbit(semaphore)
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

you can then modify the `Worker` class to acquire the semaphore before running `worker_run`:

```
class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, semaphore):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        print "Init"
        self.value = None
        self.semaphore

    def run(self):
        with self.semaphore:
            print "Running"
            self.worker_run()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def worker_run(self):
    """ implement """
    return
```

This should ensure that at most 2 `worker_run` methods are running concurrently.

---

In fact I believe you are making things more complex than what ought to be. You do *not* have to subclass `Process`. You can achieve exactly the same functionality using the `target` argument:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Semaphore
from cat import Cat
from dog import Dog
from rabbit import Rabbit

semaphore = Semaphore(2)

cat = Cat()
dog = Dog()
rabbit = Rabbit()

def run(animal, sema):
    with sema:
        animal.worker_run(*args)

cat_proc = Process(target=run, args=(cat, semaphore))
dog_proc = Process(target=run, args=(dog, semaphore))
rabbit_proc = Process(target=run, args=(rabbit, semaphore))

cat_proc.start()
dog_proc.start()
rabbit_proc.start()

cat_proc.join()
dog_proc.join()
rabbit_proc.join()
```

In fact with a little change you can get rid of the `Semaphore` and simply use the `Pool` object:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from cat import Cat
from dog import Dog
from rabbit import Rabbit


cat = Cat()
dog = Dog()
rabbit = Rabbit()

def run(animal):
    animal.worker_run()


pool = Pool(2)
pool.map(run, [cat, dog, rabbit])
```

---

The problem you had is that you cannot pass as `target` argument, or as callable to `Pool.map` a method, because methods cannot be pickled (see [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)). The `multiprocessing` modules uses the `pickle` protocol to communicate between processes so everything it handles should be pickleable.

In particular to solve the problem about unpickleable methods the standard workaround is to use a global function where you explicitly pass the instance as first argument, as I did above. This is exactly what happens with method calls, but it's done automatically by the interpreter. In this case you have to handle it explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your reply Bakuriu , the cat , dog , rabbit and worker structure and behavior is fixed , and almost impossible to change it ,  so i try to find other way to reach maximum processes concurrently .

Comment: these code is a sample code i maintain now , because there are more than 50 event(cat,dog,rabbit..) need to implement , so i say it is hard to modify or change structure

Comment: @someday I don't understand what you want to say. If your example isn't specific enough to define a solution then *you* should provide a better example of what are you doing that includes all the critical aspects. From what you have shown there's no reason why shouldn't do what I described. If this is not the case, please include the relevant information in the question and I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Hi Bakuriu , i use the Semaphore method and reachs my requirement , thanks you very much .